# django for python set up issues

Tags: python, django, command-prompt

I'm not familiar with using command prompt and having trouble at the start of the django for python set up process which i'm reading here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

My problem appears to be the 'python' command doesn't work (please see my command prompt screen shot).

I tried adding it into 'System variables' in the 'Environment Variables' as shown in the other screen shot.

Is there something i have done incorrectly here?

Also although i can get the create the initial project the only place i can create it is in the 'c:\Python\Lib\site-packages\django\bin' folder because i have to be looking at this folder in order to run the django-admin.py file.

I think the second issue is related to the first issue though i.e. if the 'python' command worked i could just run 'python django-admin.py startproject mysite' while my directory path is set to where ever i want the project to be created.

I expect i could simply move the mysite folder to where i want it but i feel i need to understand why this all isn't working as expected before moving on.

[image]

[image]

Additional:

I've now tried creating a virtual environment as suggested in the comments.
Running 'pip install virtualenvwrapper-win' appears to have worked. Running 'mkvirtualenv myproject' has not worked. It says 'C:\Users\mogwa\Envs is not
a directory although i can view this path so it is actually there.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/windows/

[image]

Comment: hi. have you try to create virtual environment with python3 and then starting project?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/windows/

Comment: I don't use windows, but it would seem to me you want to add c:\python to the path instead of making it a system variable?

Answer (score 0):

### Create Python virtual envoirement (virtual env, venv). Wait a little.

for Linux/GNU:

```
python -m venv venv
```

for Windows: (If not python in windows paths)

```
py -m venv venv
```

### Activate your new python envoirement

for Linux/GNU:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

for Windows: (Option 1)

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

for Windows: (Option 2)

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

### Install django over pip (You should see (venv))

```
pip install Django
```

Start new Django Project:

```
django-admin startproject projectname
```

For Start new Django App:

```
django-admin startapp appname
```

Comment: Trying to add a virtual environment just now with no success. I've added 'Additional' info to my OP to show the issue.

Comment: If you want to create new project. Try this trick. It's native python venv. After as I wrote last step install django. And type "django-admin startproject projectname" and for starting app "django-admin startapp appname"